# Duplicate notifications with different sounds - push notification remote

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add the custom sound in the push notification. I have added the showNotification in the background handler on the client-side (flutter), but now when the application is in the background or terminated I receive duplicate notifications, one with default sound and the other with my custom sound. Can anyone tell me how to stop showing the default background notification?

Comment: you have to show your code for us to see where the problem is and also to know what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're getting the duplicate notification because

1. you're sending a `notification message` and it is automatically displayed by the FCM SDK and,
2. you're implementing a custom notification display yourself.

The solution is to send a `data message` instead of a `notification message`.

> With FCM, you can send two types of messages to clients:
>
> - Notification messages, sometimes thought of as "display messages."
>   These are handled by the FCM SDK automatically.
> - Data messages, which
>   are handled by the client app.
>
> [Source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

Comment: so there's no way to disable the FCM SDK implementation showing the second notifications and just work with the custom?

Comment: @aolsan, you can work only with the custom by sending a `data` message. Checkout this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages